# authorization google drive curl (language c)

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I would like to upload a file from my PC with curl to my google drive (language c).
So after a lot of posts and docs, I created a google account where I defined an project using Drive API.
I'm trying to get an authorization code using my Client_ID.

curl -v -k "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" 
-d "client_id=myclientId.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://drive.google.com"

and the response is 400 Bad Request What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

redirect_uri is set up in the in your Google API project.  It should be the file that you the Authentication is returned to.  I don't think that `&redirect_uri=https://drive.google.com` is correct.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I put the path of the file but I got 400 as response. I retried my command above and I had "302 Moved Temporarily"